# The open source ads preview page is still using the old size; ads appear distorted as a result

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, open-source-advertising, sidebar

As the title says, the Open Source ads preview page at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ads/display/314722 is still using the old width for each ad, instead of the new 300px width, causing the previews for the ads to be distorted.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Someone needs to go and update the CSS to reflect the new ad size.

Comment: It's not CSS - that's backed by a table.  I'd say, remove the width and height attributes on the images and create only 3 columns per row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've changed the width to 300 and limited the number of ads to 3 per row.

With you in the next build.

---

So it looks like my fix broke the current ads - this is being reverted till ads for all sites are ready. Better the ads look right though the preview page looks a bit weird for a while.

Answer (score 11):

I would suggest removing the `height` attribute from all of the images while leaving the `width` attribute. I did it with Chrome and it looks fine.

[image: Ads Fixed]

Comment: In fact, just adding `#content img { height: auto }` to the style sheet on that page seems to be enough, although obviously the incorrect heights in the HTML should really also be fixed properly.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Fixed in soup?

Comment: @BhargavRao: In the dev branch. :) I really should push out another stable version, it's been a while since the last one. But I just made some infrastructure changes to allow page-specific CSS tweaks, so I'd kind of like to actually test that a bit first to make sure I didn't screw up something.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I guess I need to install the dev version too :)

Comment: "Fixed in soup", what?

Comment: @DavidB http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup

Comment: Huh, never saw that before.